# Creating a locator for a drop-down options which is disabled and selecting using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to create a locator for the below dropdown options and select any option from it.When i created the WebElement for an option and tried to select it,it would not get populated in the checkbox. I thought it might be due to the "disabled" tag.Im also new to Selenium. If you are able to solve it, could you please explain the solution too?

```
<select id="Dropdown">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="true">Select Options</option>
<option value="Op1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Op2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Op3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to see the options in the html, then you can directly select the option like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='Option 1']")).click();
```

if the above doesn't work then first click on the dropdown and then use the above code to select the option.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to do that:

1st you can use `select` inbuilt selenium method. You can do it like this:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Option 1"); //this will select option 1
dropdown.selectByValue("Op2"); //this will select option 2
dropdown.selectByIndex(2); //this will select option 3
```

and 2nd way is to click on `dropdown` element and then select option from the list:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown"));
dropdown.click(); //this will open list
WebElement option1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[@value='Op1']"));
option1.click(); //to select first option
```

same way you can do it for other 2 options if you want to select any of those option.

Answer (score 0):

Check if below option works for you.

```
WebElement values_dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown"));
Select drpdownop1=new Select(values_dropdown);
List<WebElement> dropdownlist=drpdownop1.getOptions();
for(int i=0;i<dropdownlist.size();i++){
String drop_down_options=dropdown.get(i).getText();
//put if condition  and select value you want.
System.out.println("dropdown values are "+drop_down_options);
}
```

Hope this helps.